# JQuery css calculating weirdness

Tags: jquery, css

The other day I tried to adjust horizontal menu items by adding left and right padding, making them weighted by text and not just adjusting them to the same width. The goal was to fill the exact space of container. The (pretty dirty) code goes like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mmenuW = $('#navinner').width(); //space to fill
  var mmCount = 0; //number of menu items
  var mmLiW = 0; //current summa width of menu items
  $('#navinner li a').each(function(){
    mmLiW += $(this).outerWidth();
    mmCount++;
  });

  alert(''); //THE NASTY ALERT, see below

  var paddPlus = Math.floor((mmenuW-mmLiW)/(mmCount*2));
  $('#navinner li a').css({'padding-left': paddPlus+'px', 'padding-right': paddPlus+'px'});
  var nmmLiW = 0; // new summa width of items
  $('#navinner li a').each(function(){
    nmmLiW += $(this).outerWidth();
  });

  var mmGap = mmenuW-nmmLiW-1; //remaining gap because of Math.floor
  alert((paddPlus)+'px');
  alert((mmGap+paddPlus)+'px');

  // adding the gap to the last elements right padding
  $('#navinner li a').last().css('padding-right', (mmGap+paddPlus)+'px');
}
```

The wierd behaviour is when the first alert has been commented out, the script works fine but there is a few pixel innacuracy against the case the alert is there.

With the first alert the script works perfect, alerts values: '','46px','58px'

Without the first alert the script leaves a gap, alerts values: '','46px','54px'

Browser: FF 6.0, JQuery: 1.7.1, online example is not present yet.

/////// edit ////////

I found out it is caused because the calculation takes places at $(document).ready but it's obviously doesn't mean all css stuff is loaded, including special fonts (in this case google webfont is used). The function runs with some fallback font I think, causing the difference. So the question reduced to how can font loading handled better, without using $(window).load. Not so elegant waiting all the images loading before formatting the menu.

Comment: Copy and pasting HTML into an editor that doesn't use it is not cool.

Comment: @MikeRobinson - Why not edit the post and fix it then? The user is new too so how about some slack?

Comment: @j08691 Cause you beat me to it by 3 seconds! :)

Comment: sorry guys, the preview was showing the right content for me. I'll try my best next time. :)